# JavaScript Regular expression for matching domain names (FQDN)

Tags: javascript, regex, domain-name, fqdn

I need to validate the domains

Valid scenarios are

`*.domain.com` (OR) `domain.com` (OR) `domain.domain.com`

Invalid:

`.domain.com` (OR) `*domain.com`

It should not allow back or front slashes at the beginning of a string

I have tried using this Expression but its failing.

```
^(?:\*\.)(http[s]?:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}
```

Comment: We live in an era where there are [over 1500 top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains), some of which are  [not even in ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Internationalized_country_code_top-level_domains). Your `\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}` isn't going to cut it any more nowadays.

Comment: You should take a look at backrefs to simplify what works. https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html and play around with https://regex101.com/ until you crack it. I wouldn't be surprised if you were re-inventing the wheel here!

Comment: how about using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-valid-domain)?

Comment: Should the regex only match __domain-names__ (FQDN) _including wildcards_ or also match __URLs__ (i.e. FQDN plus protocol/scheme and port)? Maybe you can also describe the context (application, use-case, purpose) for your validation.

Answer (score 0):

On *regex101.com* you can **search the library**. Even if there is nothing suitable in flavour *ECMA-Script/JavaScript*, I found one in *PCRE*: [Domain with protocol, Third-Level-Domain, Second-Level-Domain, Top-Level-Domain and Port.](https://regex101.com/library/xS0iY6) and forked it to match your need:

```
^((\w+)\:\/\/)?(([\w\-]+|\*)\.)*([\w\-]+)\.(\w+)(\:(\d+))?$
```

> **UPDATED**: [previous regex (v2)](https://regex101.com/r/jdVjD3/2/tests) searched only for parts and thus matches also invalid examples because a part was valid. Fixed it by adding *begin* `^` and *end* `$`. Now the regex rejects the invalid (`*domain.com` or `.domain.com`).

See my [regex (v3) including tests](https://regex101.com/r/jdVjD3/3/tests)

Comment: Fixed the regex so it passes all your 4 specified test-cases. Please try!